# Changing a group box's text, background, or outlined color

Tags: c, winapi, colors, groupbox

I have a dialog item (a Group Box), I would like to change the background color of.  I have read the posts I could find on here that are similar, but still have a few more basic questions.  My thoughts on how to accomplish this task are to first catch the ID, and change it by using WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC.

I would be happy with changing the Group Box's outline and text, or the entire background of only the Group box (not the entire dialog).  I also think I might have to change the static text area to achieve this (the static text area inside the group box which has an ID), but I'm not certain.

My code below is attempting to find a matching ID with the ID of the group box I would like to change.  If I find the match then I change the bgColor and TextColor.  However, I never find the match.  I believe the ID value is around 5000 or so off the ID Group Box.  If I force a match between the two (by statically giving the ID the number of the group box), it changes the wrong part of the dialog box to the bg color I'm passing in.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, should I try a different approach?

```
long id;
static HBRUSH chgTextColor, chgBackColor;


case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
  id = GetWindow((HWND)lParam, GWL_ID);
  if ( id == IDC_GROUP_BOX )
  {
    chgTextColor = RGB(0,255,255);
    chgBackColor = RBG(0,255,0);
    SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, chgTextColor);
    SetBkColor((HDC)wParam, chgBackColor);
    hChgBrush = CreateSolidBrush(chgBackColor);
    return (long)hChgBrush
  }
  break;
```

Comment: [GetWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515.aspx) returns a window handle, not a control ID. And it doesn't have a flag `GWL_ID`. You probably meant to call [GetDlgCtrlID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645478.aspx) instead. Also, you are (or would be) leaking a brush object per `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message that matches your control. And your return value is the wrong type: A `long` is 32 bits on 64-bit Windows as well. This should be an `INT_PTR`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'll give GetDlgCtrlID a whirl.

Comment: I wasn't able to change the group box color ( maybe its transparent?), but I was able to access the static text field with your changes.  I think thats pretty good.  If you reply with the changes as an answer I'll accept the answer.  Cheers.